# I'm trying to compare mean of the company volume with daily volume of the same company and find the difference in pandas. I've made groupby on company

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, pandas-groupby

**I'm trying to compare mean of the company volume with daily volume of the same company and find the difference in pandas. I've made groupby on company and got mean of each company volume. I want the mean to compare to daily volume of same company.**

The code below is :

```
vol_grp.mean()
```

Output is :

```
            Volume
Company 
20MICRONS   947802.086957
3MINDIA     3881.608696
5PAISA      69606.521739
AAKASH      49254.217391
AARON       46435.583333
... ...
ZODJRDMKJ   50541.666667
ZOTA        36271.130435
ZUARI       285558.652174
ZUARIGLOB   149646.347826
ZYDUSWELL   72017.826087
1397 rows × 1 columns
```

The actual data is

```
    Date           Company      Volume
1   03-MAY-2021   20MICRONS     192281
4   03-MAY-2021   3MINDIA       1707
7   03-MAY-2021   5PAISA        81581
16  03-MAY-2021   AAKASH        35865
17  03-MAY-2021   AARON         1255
... ... ... ...
47160   03-JUN-2021 ZODIACLOTH  75966
47162   03-JUN-2021 ZOTA        470978
47163   03-JUN-2021 ZUARI       137563
47164   03-JUN-2021 ZUARIGLOB   51545
47165   03-JUN-2021 ZYDUSWELL   24350
```

**For example I've 20MICRONS company mean, i want to compare with daily volume of 20MICRONS company. If i have 30 days information of 20MICRONS volume, my mean should compare with those 30 values and should return 30 difference values. Similarly for all other companies**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I created this sample df

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date= [dt(2021,1,i) for i in [1]*4+[2]*4+[3]*4], 
                       company= ["AAPL", "FB", "NVDA", "AMZN"]*3,
                       volume= [randint(100,10000) for _ in range(12)]))
df

        date company  volume
0  2021-01-01    AAPL    1470
1  2021-01-01      FB    7478
2  2021-01-01    NVDA    9156
3  2021-01-01    AMZN    5972
4  2021-01-02    AAPL    9836
5  2021-01-02      FB    1990
6  2021-01-02    NVDA    5380
7  2021-01-02    AMZN    1338
8  2021-01-03    AAPL    9235
9  2021-01-03      FB    3708
10 2021-01-03    NVDA     480
11 2021-01-03    AMZN    2805
```

Then I created a group and was able to get each company's mean the same way you did:

```
grp = df.groupby("company")
grp.mean()
              volume
company             
AAPL     6847.000000
AMZN     3371.666667
FB       4392.000000
NVDA     5005.333333
```

Then I just merged the mean series with the original df:

```
# on = "company" will make it align the values on the company values
merged = df.merge(grp.mean(), on= "company", suffixes= ("_daily", "_mean"))
merged
         date company  volume_daily  volume_mean
0  2021-01-01    AAPL          1470  6847.000000
1  2021-01-02    AAPL          9836  6847.000000
2  2021-01-03    AAPL          9235  6847.000000
3  2021-01-01      FB          7478  4392.000000
4  2021-01-02      FB          1990  4392.000000
5  2021-01-03      FB          3708  4392.000000
6  2021-01-01    NVDA          9156  5005.333333
7  2021-01-02    NVDA          5380  5005.333333
8  2021-01-03    NVDA           480  5005.333333
9  2021-01-01    AMZN          5972  3371.666667
10 2021-01-02    AMZN          1338  3371.666667
11 2021-01-03    AMZN          2805  3371.666667
```

And finally, I created the difference column by doing a good old subtraction:

```
merged["difference"] = merged["volume_daily"] - merged["volume_mean"]
merged
         date company  volume_daily  volume_mean   difference
0  2021-01-01    AAPL          1470  6847.000000 -5377.000000
1  2021-01-02    AAPL          9836  6847.000000  2989.000000
2  2021-01-03    AAPL          9235  6847.000000  2388.000000
3  2021-01-01      FB          7478  4392.000000  3086.000000
4  2021-01-02      FB          1990  4392.000000 -2402.000000
5  2021-01-03      FB          3708  4392.000000  -684.000000
6  2021-01-01    NVDA          9156  5005.333333  4150.666667
7  2021-01-02    NVDA          5380  5005.333333   374.666667
8  2021-01-03    NVDA           480  5005.333333 -4525.333333
9  2021-01-01    AMZN          5972  3371.666667  2600.333333
10 2021-01-02    AMZN          1338  3371.666667 -2033.666667
11 2021-01-03    AMZN          2805  3371.666667  -566.666667
```

[DataFrame.merge docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge)

for percentage difference:

```
merged["%_diff"] = merged["difference"]/merged["volume_mean"]*100
merged
         date company  volume_daily  volume_mean   difference     %_diff
0  2021-01-01    AAPL          1470  6847.000000 -5377.000000 -78.530743
1  2021-01-02    AAPL          9836  6847.000000  2989.000000  43.654155
2  2021-01-03    AAPL          9235  6847.000000  2388.000000  34.876588
3  2021-01-01      FB          7478  4392.000000  3086.000000  70.264117
4  2021-01-02      FB          1990  4392.000000 -2402.000000 -54.690346
5  2021-01-03      FB          3708  4392.000000  -684.000000 -15.573770
6  2021-01-01    NVDA          9156  5005.333333  4150.666667  82.924880
7  2021-01-02    NVDA          5380  5005.333333   374.666667   7.485349
8  2021-01-03    NVDA           480  5005.333333 -4525.333333 -90.410229
9  2021-01-01    AMZN          5972  3371.666667  2600.333333  77.123085
10 2021-01-02    AMZN          1338  3371.666667 -2033.666667 -60.316362
11 2021-01-03    AMZN          2805  3371.666667  -566.666667 -16.806723
```

Comment: Can we get percentage between volume_mean and difference like difference value is 15% increase when compared to volume_mean and same for decrease?

Comment: it's just a normal percent calculation ;)